# How to print the ACTUAL SQLAlchemy query to troubleshoot: SQLAlchemy filter statement replaces filter critieria with %(column_name_1)s

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a SQLAlchemy query that looks like this:

```
query = db.session.query(
    Place.name,
    Place.population,
).filter(Place.population==8000)
```

But when I print the query, it comes out as:

```
SELECT place.name AS place_name, place.population AS place_population
FROM place
WHERE place.population = %(population_1)s
```

I can't figure out why it keeps replacing my filter criteria with `%(population_1)s`.  This query is part of a Flask app, maybe there's something there I'm not understanding?

Edit: changed the Title to be more descriptive of the actual problem.

Comment: how are you printing the query?

Comment: @mad_ `print(query)`

Comment: That will never print the argument passed. `print(stmt.compile(dialect=postgresql.dialect(),compile_kwargs={"literal_binds": True}))` if you are using postgres otherwise change the dialect and post the result.

Comment: @mad_ I got `NameError: name 'postgresql' is not defined` .  If I try `print(query.statement.compile())`, I get `SELECT place.name, place.population FROM place WHERE place.population = :population_1`.  It's a postgres db so I'm not sure why the dialect argument isn't working.  Also, I noticed you used `stmt`.  Could I be causing this by naming my variable `query`?

Comment: `print(query.statement.compile(compile_kwargs={"literal_binds"))`. You can literally name anything you want. You need to import the dialect.`from sqlalchemy.dialects import postgresql
query = statement.compile(dialect=postgresql.dialect())`

Comment: It's working exactly as it should. That's a named placeholder, waiting to be replaced with the given value (after conversion) by your DB-API driver in use. In other words SQLA compiled the query, and placed placeholders for values in a format understood by your driver. It will then pass the query and the values to the driver when executing.

Comment: I get `SELECT place.name, place.population FROM place WHERE place.population = 8000`.  But when I run the query, it's not applying the filter.  I've done some more digging and it appears I'm misunderstanding how Place.query works. I have a separate function that takes the query as an argument and that turns this query into a dictionary.  So I moved the print statement into that function and realized it's querying all the columns in the table. The function uses Flask.Paginate, which I can't get to work if I use db.session.query() instead of Places.query. Is there an equivalent to Places.query?

Comment: @sunday_funday, `Is there an equivalent to Places.query?` is a completely new question not related to the subject of this one. If you are still having issues you should open up a new question.

Comment: @SuperShoot you’re right. I’ll post it separately. Thanks!

Comment: @mad_ your print statement was the answer to this specific question.  If you want to post it as an answer, I can accept it as the solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is behaving just the way it should. It's just that how you print the query.

```
from sqlalchemy.dialects import postgresql 
query = statement.compile(dialect=postgresql.dialect(),compile_kwargs={"literal_binds": True})
print(query) # will print the compiled query statement againt the dialect.
```

Comment: I was putting this print statement in the wrong place. "Places.query" was a flask-sqlalchemy-specific keyword that I was passing to another function to actually run the query.  My variable "query" wasn't being sent anywhere.  When I moved the print statement into the other function, I realized my error.  Confusing variable naming and lack of understanding.  Thanks!